# Style a WPF DataGrid row header when the selected cell resides in that row?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that is configured to only allow a single cell selection, i.e.:-

```
SelectionMode="Single"
SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

What I'm trying to do is change the background of the *row header* of whichever row contains the currently selected cell. I've come up with the following so far, but it isn't working.

Here is the XAML style, which binds the background property to a multi-value converter. The converter is bound to the header's `DataGridRow` *and* the `SelectedCells` property of the `DataGrid`:-

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dataGridHeaderBackgroundConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" 
                         Path="SelectedCells"
                         Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The multi-converter's `Convert` method looks like this (I've removed null checking code to keep it concise):-

```
var row = values[0] as DataGridRow;
var selectedCells = values[1] as IList<DataGridCellInfo>;
var selectedCell = selectedCells[0];

return selectedCell.Item == row.Item ? Colors.Red : Colors.LightGray;
```

The method only seems to get called when the DataGrid is initially rendered (when there are no selections). It doesn't get called after a cell has been selected, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update your style as follows and write the EqualityConverter which would be a MultiValueConverter to be used to bind the DataGrid's `CurrentCell` and RowHeader context in the `DataTrigger`. So this trigger will be fired everytime you select the cell on your `DataGrid`.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding Path="CurrentCell" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

and in converter's `Convert` method:

```
            if(values[0] == ((DataGridCellInfo)values[1]).Item)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

Tested it.. worked well

Comment: Thanks for this. I was too hung up on the "Selected..." properties and completely missed "CurrentCell"!

Comment: Nice solution, but do you have any ideas how to do the same when SelectionMode is not Single? In this case binding to CurrentCell does not make sense :(

Answer (score 1):

Nitin's solution works perfectly, but during updating data in my data grid, this warning is raised:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentCell; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Any solution to get rid of this warning?

Anyway here is another working approach...

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="black" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsRowSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: This works nicely for Full Row selection or if the user selected via the row header.
Unfortunately, if the selection unit is for Cell, IsRowSelected will not be true. For that, the accepted answer should work. Anyway, voting up both answers.